# query to display the highest salaries of employees by age

Tags: sql

Can you help me? Need to get a list of the highest salaries of employee with the sample by age,first name and last name

Input:

```
Age        FirstName     LastName      SAL     
---------- ----------    ----------  ----------
30         Andy          Donald        175     
31         Petr          Pess          295     
30         John          Jacky         453     
31         Bob           Bobby         385     
29         Eric          Rice          957
```

Answer should be

```
Age        FirstName     LastName      SAL     
---------- ----------    ----------  ----------
31         Bob           Bobby         385     
30         John          Jacky         453     
29         Eric          Rice          957
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should include the homework tag. What have you tried that didn't work. Checkout the FAQ on How to Ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @AdamPorad, I'm starting to think that when the user doesn't include an RDBMS-specific tag, it must be homework. :)

Answer (score 3):

Get all employees for which there is no employee with the same age and with a higher salary:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees e1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM employees e2
  WHERE e1.age = e2.age
  AND e1.sal < e2.sal
)
ORDER BY age DESC
```

If two employees have the same age *and* salary, both will be returned... This query will work on any database

Answer (score 3):

If you have window/analytic functions available (you don't mention an RDBMS in the OP), you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Age, FirstName, LastName, SAL
         , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY SAL DESC) AS ranknum
      FROM employees
) WHERE ranknum = 1
```

This will work even when two or more employees of the same age have the same salary - both will be returned. It will also allow you to get the 2nd highest salary, etc., if you want (just change `ranknum = 1` to `ranknum = 2`, etc.).

**Edit:** FYI, this will work in Oracle, SQL Server, and PostgreSQL at least.

Comment: @burhan, check out RANK() as well. The difference between the two is that (for example) if there are two tied for first, RANK() will return 3 for the next value while DENSE_RANK() will return 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, the following should work:

```
select * from
(select * from myTable order by age desc, sal desc) sq
group by age
```

(Although it won't return multiple rows for employees of the same age on the same salary.)

Comment: Just curious, but can you explain how this works? The outer select includes fields that are not aggregated? I didn't even think this is valid SQL when using GROUP BY?

Comment: It's only valid in MySQL, as far as I know - unaggregated fields in grouped MySQL queries have the value from the first row in the group returned.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that. That opens a lot of possibilities for some novel solutions to a lot of queries.

Comment: @njr: I'd strongly advise against this practice. You shouldn't make any assumptions about the value returned from column-references that are not part of the `group by` clause or explicitly aggregated. This query could break in a future version of MySQL as [documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html): *"The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."*. In other words, Mark's solution might work *"by well-designed coincidence"* :-)